# Gulp watch sass causes terminal to hang - is that the point?

Tags: terminal, gulp

So I just got my hands dirty with Gulp. I have never worked with Grunt, but it seems that Gulp is the new big thing. Everything seems to work fine. I have successfully compiled SCSS into CSS with the following gulpfile.js:

```
// Include gulp
var gulp = require('gulp'); 

// Include Our Plugins
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');


// Compile Our Sass
gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src('./scss/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'));
});

// Rerun the task when a file changes
gulp.task('watch', function () {
  gulp.watch('scss/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
});

// Default Task
gulp.task('default', ['sass', 'watch']);
```

Thing is: When I run Gulp default in the terminal it starts the script, but never ends it. I'm assuming this is the point, that in order for Gulp to watch my files - it has to keep running.

It's on standby with this:

```
[gulp] Running 'sass'...
[gulp] Finished 'sass' in 8.47 ms
```

If that's the case - how do I stop it from running without closing and reopening the Terminal? I'm sorry if this is simple but i have no clue when it comes to the Terminal.

Comment: Press CTRL+C to end the current process.

Comment: Thank you!! so my assumtions were right - it is suppose to be running until i stop it myself right?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

gulp watch is designed to watch the file changes, it acts as a running process.

The README shows an example of its usage: [gulp-watch](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#gulpwatchglob-tasks-or-gulpwatchglob--opts-cb)

The command: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> will stop the process.

Once started modifying any file in the `watch` directive will trigger the action in the reload. You currently do not have any action for your watch, this will trigger a action when the sass files change:

```
gulp.watch('./scss/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
```

Comment: The control-c was what i was looking for, but the gulp.run seem to be depricated. And my code works without. Thanks!